# Re-create table with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I used Hibernate to create an annotated class, and it worked fine for the first time I ran the application.

The problem is that I did a `DROP TABLE` using psql and now I want hibernate to re-create that table automatically again, based on my annotated class.

If I run the application again, the table is not created and I get an Exception saying that such table doesn't exist (when I try to access it).

What should I do to re-create that table, just as I was creating it for the first time?

Comment: have you set the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`?  ref: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-misc-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to set property

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update`

or generate ddl manually with

`java -cp hibernate_classpaths org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport options mapping_files`

with this tool you can export ddl to a file and execute script manually or do it automatically (mapping_files is optional)